# @angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'HammerLoader'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-datatables

I tried to run "ng build", I'm getting following error.

"ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/common-behaviors/common-module.d.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"../Frontend/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'HammerLoader'."

pacakge.json contain with "@angular/platform-browser" and "@angular/material". I'm trying to use here angular material table.

I couldn't figure it why this error is coming and the possible solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check the @angular/material version, the new version only work with angular 7. Try install older version (p.e `npm i @angular/material@6.4.7`). This works for me.

Comment: @Tenzolinho Have you checked if the major version of angular is the same as the angular version? If you use angular 5 your material version should also be 5

Comment: I just needed to restart visual studio code and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is Just a Version Problem, Try This

```
npm i @angular/material@6.4.7
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing angular material again

> `ng add @angular/material`

[angular material - get started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)