# How to create a proper iframe with a variable

Tags: html, youtube

I'm trying to create a tag for a Youtube embed video where the src comes from a variable value of a database

The tag goes like this:

```
<iframe class="img-fluid w-100" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and I'm trying to substitute it like this:

```
<iframe class="img-fluid w-100" width="560" height="315" src="{{frontPageConfig.recentVideos2.linkURL}}"
            frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But it does not work with or without {{variable}}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to sanitize the URL as is done in

[Correct way Provide DomSanitizer to Component with Angular 2 RC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438039/correct-way-provide-domsanitizer-to-component-with-angular-2-rc6)

Though you can find somre problems with the versions:

[@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'HammerLoader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968879/angular-platform-browser-platform-browser-has-no-exported-member-hammerloade)